# Converting Numpy Array to OpenCV Array

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I'm trying to convert a 2D Numpy array, representing a black-and-white image, into a 3-channel OpenCV array (i.e. an RGB image).

Based on [code samples](https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/browser/trunk/opencv/samples/python2/find_obj.py) and [the docs](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/miscellaneous_image_transformations.html#cv-cvtcolor) I'm attempting to do this via Python like:

```
import numpy as np, cv
vis = np.zeros((384, 836), np.uint32)
h,w = vis.shape
vis2 = cv.CreateMat(h, w, cv.CV_32FC3)
cv.CvtColor(vis, vis2, cv.CV_GRAY2BGR)
```

However, the call to CvtColor() is throwing the following cpp-level Exception:

```
OpenCV Error: Image step is wrong () in cvSetData, file /build/buildd/opencv-2.1.0/src/cxcore/cxarray.cpp, line 902
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /build/buildd/opencv-2.1.0/src/cxcore/cxarray.cpp:902: error: (-13)  in function cvSetData

Aborted
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: From the docs for `CvtColor` "src – The source image, 8-bit unsigned, 16-bit unsigned ( CV_16UC... ) or single-precision floating-point".  I notice that your numpy array is `np.uint32`.  This may explain `OpenCV Error: Image step is wrong () in cvSetData`.  I notice the code samples use a different data type: see `vis = np.zeros((max(h1, h2), w1+w2), np.uint8)`.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Your code can be fixed as follows:

```
import numpy as np, cv
vis = np.zeros((384, 836), np.float32)
h,w = vis.shape
vis2 = cv.CreateMat(h, w, cv.CV_32FC3)
vis0 = cv.fromarray(vis)
cv.CvtColor(vis0, vis2, cv.CV_GRAY2BGR)
```

Short explanation:

1. `np.uint32` data type is not supported by OpenCV (it supports `uint8`, `int8`, `uint16`, `int16`, `int32`, `float32`, `float64`)
2. `cv.CvtColor` can't handle numpy arrays so both arguments has to be converted to OpenCV type. `cv.fromarray` do this conversion.
3. Both arguments of `cv.CvtColor` must have the same depth. So I've changed source type to 32bit float to match the ddestination.

Also I recommend you use newer version of OpenCV python API because it uses numpy arrays as primary data type:

```
import numpy as np, cv2
vis = np.zeros((384, 836), np.float32)
vis2 = cv2.cvtColor(vis, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
```

Comment: Just update that newer versions of OpenCV do not require such conversion anymore since the OpenCV array is an NumPy array.

Answer (score 8):

This is what worked for me...

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

#Created an image (really an ndarray) with three channels 
new_image = np.ndarray((3, num_rows, num_cols), dtype=int)

#Did manipulations for my project where my array values went way over 255
#Eventually returned numbers to between 0 and 255

#Converted the datatype to np.uint8
new_image = new_image.astype(np.uint8)

#Separated the channels in my new image
new_image_red, new_image_green, new_image_blue = new_image

#Stacked the channels
new_rgb = np.dstack([new_image_red, new_image_green, new_image_blue])

#Displayed the image
cv2.imshow("WindowNameHere", new_rgbrgb)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Answer (score -1):

The simplest solution would be to use Pillow lib:

```
from PIL import Image

image = Image.fromarray(<your_numpy_array>.astype(np.uint8))
```

And you can use it as an image.

Comment: OP asks to convert a `2D Numpy array, representing a black-and-white image, into a 3-channel OpenCV array`. Your solution does not answer to the question.