# Why is ndarray displayed as a black image?

Tags: python, image, python-2.7, opencv, numpy

I try to convert ndarray to image:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

def main():
    #...
    data_array = []
    data_array.append((255, 255, 255))
    data_array.append((255, 255, 255))
    # http://pastebin.com/iUs6ebBU

    new_image = np.array(data_array).reshape((height, width, 3))

    r,g,b = cv2.split(new_image)
    img_bgr = cv2.merge([b,g,r])

    cv2.imshow('image',img_bgr)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
```

But I see only black image, not mine. What is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution: [np.uint32 data type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7587819/1756750) is not supported by OpenCV.

I convert `int32` to `uint8`, and now It works.