# convert rgb image from numpy array to HSV (opencv)

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

When I'm converting an image from RGB to HSV, if the image come straight from opencv, everything is alright:

```
img = cv2.imread(path)
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
```

However, if this image come from a numpy array of shape (nb_of_images, 224, 224, 3) there is some complications.

Here is my import function:

```
def import_images(path_list):
    path_len = len(path_list)
    images = numpy.zeros((path_len, 224, 224, 3), dtype = numpy.float64)

    for pos in range(path_len):
        testimg = cv2.imread(path_list[pos])

        if(testimg is not None):
            testimg = cv2.cvtColor(testimg, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            testimg = cv2.resize(testimg, (224, 224))
            images[pos, :, :, :] = testimg
    return images
```

And now, here is my trouble:

```
images = import_images(["./test/dog.jpg"])
img = images[0, :, :, :]
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2HSV)
```

The console give the following error:

`cv2.error: /io/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp:11073: error: (-215) depth == 0 || depth == 2 || depth == 5 in function cvtColor`

I tried to change the image type:

```
img.astype(numpy.float32)
```

but the console give the same error

What am I missing ?

--edit--

I'm using
python 3.5

numpy (1.14.2)

opencv-python (3.4.0.12)

Comment: May be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7587490/converting-numpy-array-to-opencv-array) helps you!

Comment: @RickM. Maybe that last answer, the rest of it is using ancient deprecated opencv API.

Comment: @DanMašek Difficult to pin point since OP hasn't mentioned the API version. @Mel Abgrall There could be an issue in this line as well `images[pos, :, :, :] = testimg`

Comment: @RickM. made an edit with versions. What kind of issue can cause       images[pos, :, :, :] = testimg  ?

Comment: @RickM. Not that difficult, given that OP used exclusively the new API.

Comment: Mel, does `images` really have to be `np.float64`?

Comment: no, I can also work with np.float32 images

Comment: @DanMašek this was the source of the issue thanks ! I'll post an answer with the correct code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the datatype of the elements in `images`. Right now it's `np.float64`.

Let's look at the assert in the [C++ source code](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/3.4.0/modules/imgproc/src/color.cpp#L11073)

```
CV_Assert( depth == CV_8U || depth == CV_16U || depth == CV_32F );
```

Translated to `numpy`, this means the data type of elements has to be `np.uint8`, `np.uint16`, or `np.float32` for `cvtColor` to work at all. There are other more specific checks for some of the color conversions as well.

As you mention that 32 bit floats are sufficient for your use-case, you can do

```
images = numpy.zeros((path_len, 224, 224, 3), dtype = numpy.float32)
```

Comment: revised this line in function import_images:     images = numpy.zeros((path_len, 224, 224, 3), dtype = numpy.float32)