# Spinnaker sdk convert image to Opencv format Python

Tags: python, flir, spinnaker-cam

i have a Flir A615 camera and im getting data from it with this code:

```
image_result = cam.GetNextImage()
image_data = image_result.GetNDArray()
```

then to show im using `matplotlib`

```
plt.imshow(image_data, cmap='afmhot')
```

but i cant use it on opencv like

```
cv2.imshow("frame",image_data)
```

some one know how to convert the `PySpin.Image` to `Opencv` format?

Comment: Add `cv2.waitKey(0)` so that it will show the image until you press the space bar. See https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html#ga5628525ad33f52eab17feebcfba38bd7 and https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html#ga453d42fe4cb60e5723281a89973ee563

Comment: thank you i will try it

Comment: i see you tagged this question with Spinnaker but this tag is for the devops software tool Spinnaker. Maybe there should be a different spinnaker-Photograph tag.
I hope you find your solution soon.

Answer (score 1):

The PySpin image.GetNDArray method converts and returns the image to a numpy array. In this answer you can find the conversion rules for numpy -> opencv format: [Converting Numpy Array to OpenCV Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7587490/converting-numpy-array-to-opencv-array)